# I'm getting a semicolon error in PHP and can't understand why it's a problem

Tags: php, parse-error, stripslashes

This is the error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home1/goldensu/public_html/camira/contactForm.php on line 155

and this is the code:

```
      $sendMessage = "Someone is interested in becoming a reseller or installer.<br /><br /><br />
        <b><u>Country</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($country)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Company Name</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($companyName)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Office Address</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($officeAddress)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Company Phone</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($companyPhone)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Company Email</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($companyEmail)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Web page</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($webPage."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Number of emplyees</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($numberEmployees)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Yearly turnover</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($turnover)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Marketing Activities</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($marketingActivities)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Annual marketing budget</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($marketingBudget)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Current renewable energy products</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($energyProducts)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Length of agreements</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($agreements)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Territories</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($territories)."<br /><br />\n
        <b><u>Staff Qualifications</u>:</b> "
        .stripslashes($staffQualifications)."<br /><br />\n";
```

It's complaining about the semicolon at the end.  Is it something stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
.stripslashes($webPage."<br /><br />\n
```

it appears you have missed a closing bracket ) :

```
.stripslashes($webPage)."<br /><br />\n
```

Answer (score 1):

In this context it's most likely a missing paranthesis in the previous expressions.

It seems this one:

```
    .stripslashes($webPage."<br /><br />\n
    <b><u>Number of emplyees</u>:</b> "
```

(A error that could have been avoided by applying a magic_quotes workaround [centrally](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).)

Comment: You just inadvertently pointed out a typo in my code too, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, didn't notice. But you should really get rid of the overflowing stripslashes() use.

Answer (score 0):

Just seen the missing closing bracket... Silly me!

```
.stripslashes($webPage."<br /><br />\n
```